# Output not execite all code in C, just a part of it.Maybe the problem is not with the code but with my text editor

Tags: c, terminal, codeblocks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int age = 18;
    double GPA = 3.7;
    char lambang = 'A';
    char name[] = "Riszky Hermawan";
    printf("Congratulations %s \n", name );
    printf("You has finished this semester with : \n");
    printf("GPA =  %lf  \n", GPA);
    printf("Grade = %c \n", lambang);
    printf("HAPPY BIRTHDAY ON YOUR %d  \n", age);

    return 0;
}
```

so, when i run it, it was just show

```
Congratulation Riszky Hermawan
You has finished this semester with:
GPA = 3.7
```

^that's it. it's not printing all code. Do you know what is the problem? Maybe its not the code, but with compiler(?) i dont know , please help me. Sorry for bad english, thank you very much

Comment: Cannot reproduce, sorry: all five lines were output.

Comment: How do you run it? It works fine for me.

Comment: My only niggle is a missing space in your output between `with` and `:` so was it a different version of the program you run? Also a missing `s` from `Congratulations`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, well spotted, yep that's a red flag.

Comment: ...and a missing space after `GPA = `. It's better to copy/paste code and output. If you did, then you forgot to recompile / run the wrong version.